# Full carbon fiber 29er suspension mountain bike from AliBaba

Tags: mountain-bike, carbon, full-suspension

Does anybody have any experience with this bike?

[Full carbon fiber 29er suspension mountain bike with Deore XT 30 speed groupset](http://gubchina.en.alibaba.com/productshowimg/704228598-212622838/Full_carbon_fiber_29er_suspension_mountain_bike_with_Deore_XT_30_speed_groupset.html)

[image]

I'm looking to buy my first expensive mountain bike and trying to decide between this and the [Giant Trance sx 27.5](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-us/bikes/model/trance.sx.27.5/14834/66295/). Also, on the bike above, can someone tell me what the rear suspension travel is? Is it possible that it is just 37.5 mm?!

> DT Swiss M212 Rear Shocks - Eye to eye:165m/m, Travel:37.5m/m, Alloy,
>   Black anodized, Air, Elastomer negativ spring, Oil damping, Rebound,
>   Lockout

I ride on Arabian mountains.. don't do a lot of jumps, but need to climb and descend very rough, dry and rocky rocky sections. Can somebody have a look at the specs and tell me if it is a good bike?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: 37.5mm will be the travel of the shock. How this translates to wheel travel depends on the bike geometry

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange! Shopping, or product recommendation questions are frequently downvoted and flagged for moderator attention because they quickly become obsolete and often invite opinions rather than factual answers. See the [help center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for reasons why questions are put on hold and tips on how to revise this question.

Comment: This would be worth reopening if it were reworded more generally to encompass a higher level concept. Perhaps "name brand vs generic high end bikes" or "buying high end bikes from Alibaba.com"

Comment: Relevant news - its worth considering the after-sales support.  A coworker broke his 12 year old Giant MTB frame - the right chainstay snapped at the weld.  Giant offers a lifetime warranty on their frames, so he got the current model bike for nothing, and the old bike was taken back for analysis.   Your Chinese supplier won't go that far.

Answer (score 8):

Ask yourself this- would you buy a car off of Alibaba to save a few bucks, or would you fork over a little more money and buy a Honda/Toyota/whatever?

Buy the name brand bike. If your Alibaba bike's headtube snaps off on a gnarly high speed descent, who's going to do something about it? Not Alibaba, and good luck getting the manufacturer from god knows where to do anything about the catastrophic failure of their no-name bike.

Buying the bike pictured is a total gamble, not just in terms of your money, but in terms of your safety as well. Play it safe, pay a little more, and stick with the Giant- they've got a great reputation, they make great bikes, and they back them up.

Alibaba is for widgets. A bike is not a widget.

Comment: Doubly true for anything carbon fiber.

Comment: Better answer than I was thinking up, I would not have put it that bluntly......

Comment: Tone not intended. Too much coffee perhaps. I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you. I asked for bike geometry and they said OEM did not provide them with that info! It's just so tempting cuz it's so light and understated (not a big fan of flashy colours and decals on american bikes). As for warranty, I'm not sure that I can do much with recognized brand warranty in Yemen.

From a spec point of view, how do the components of the two bikes compare? Is one clearly lower specced than the other, or are they comparable?